# xsl:value-of used as xsl:element name

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, value-of

I have an incoming XML file with a list structure:

```
<list>
  <listItem>
    <name>elementOne</name>
    <value>elementOneValue</name>
  </listItem>
  <listItem>
    <name>elementTwo</name>
    <value>elementTwoValue</name>
  </listItem>
</list>
```

Which I am trying to convert to this structure:

```
<elementOne>elementOneValue</elementOne>
<elementTwo>elementTwoValue</elementTwo>
```

This is easy logic to implement with XSL, but I'm running into complications.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/list/listItem">
  <xsl:element name="<xsl:value-of select="name"/>">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Doesn't work because I assume the sequential double quotes are breaking the `<xsl:element>` tag

```
<xsl:for-each select="/list/listItem">
  <<xsl:value-of select="name"/>>
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  </<xsl:value-of select="name"/>>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Doesn't work because I can't use `<<` or `>>` and

```
<xsl:for-each select="/list/listItem">
  &lt;<xsl:value-of select="name"/>&gt;
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  &lt;/<xsl:value-of select="name"/>&gt;
</xsl:for-each>
```

Doesn't work because I end up with > and < in my code instead of XML parseable `<` or `>`.  I expected this to be a very easy solution but I can't find any records for it on the internet.  What is the simple fix I'm overlooking?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution, using `<xsl:element>`. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Here is a complete and short solution, using the [`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-element) XSLT instruction**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="listItem">
   <xsl:element name="{name}">
     <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<list>
    <listItem>
        <name>elementOne</name>
        <value>elementOneValue</value>
    </listItem>
    <listItem>
        <name>elementTwo</name>
        <value>elementTwoValue</value>
    </listItem>
</list>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<elementOne>elementOneValue</elementOne>
<elementTwo>elementTwoValue</elementTwo>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of the `<xsl:element>` instruction** to create an element with statically unknown name.
2. **The use of AVT** ([**Attribute-Value-Template**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#dt-attribute-value-template)) to specify the `name` attribute in a compact and more readable way.
3. **It is possible for an error to be raised** if the string values of `elementOne` and `elementTwo` do not obey the lexical/syntactic rules for an element name (QName).

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can use curly braces instead of `<xsl:value-of>`:

```
<xsl:element name="{name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: I was looking for something else but this is the answer that I was looking for... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it but this sould work...

```
   <xsl:for-each select="/list/listItem">
      <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="name"/>
      <xsl:element name="$elemName">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: close but you need to escape the variable <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">