# name an element in XSL based on data

Tags: xslt

My source data is setup like this

```
<Fields>
<Field Name="CustomerPORef" Type="co-customerporef">508823</Field>
</fields>
```

MY XSL is setup like this

```
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</tr>
```

To output this

```
<tr>
<td>CustomerPORef</td>
<td>508823</td>
</tr>
```

I want to change the XSL to use the  value as the element name so it looks like this

```
<CustomerPORef>508823</CustomerPORef>
```

Comment: What's your source XML? What does your current XSL look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xsl:value-of used as xsl:element name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708551/xslvalue-of-used-as-xslelement-name)

Comment: I agree with @MattJones, this is a duplicate question. The only difference between your question and the duplicate question is that you will need to use the `Name` attribute instead of the `name` element. Like: `<xsl:element name="{@Name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>`